# Coding alternative shaded rows?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want alternative rows in my table to be shaded. what is the best way to do this, javascript, rails?

Today, i do a simple <% num % 2%>, but this is such a common operation that i think there should be a smarter way to do it

Comment: Why something smarter? I don't think it gets any smarter or more compact than that, it's language agnostic and common sense, etc etc - don't fix if it ain't broken! Modulo is fancy enough.

Comment: Doing this with JavaScript will just add to the page load time of the user. Until all the browsers support CSS3 fully, doing it on the server is your best bet.

Comment: If you are willing to drop drop IE support, checkout the `nth-child` selectors for CSS3.

Comment: I'd rather do it in browser using JavaScript because I prefer visitors have a half second extra to a page they know is loading, than a half second waiting for the server before any content is served.

Comment: Your server is probably by magnitudes faster than the client's javascript.

Comment: +1: Got people talking. Always interesting with a healthy discussion concerning programming design choices

Comment: @anurag Cannot wait till all browsers support HTML5 and CSS3!!

Comment: @ming I cannot wait to see IEs market share go down, so I can safely use all HTML5 and CSS3 features without hesitating :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to do it on the server side, rails intended way is for you to use the "cycle" method, this will handle the modulus 2 stuff, but will also handle namespacing if you need to do nested alternating shading.

```
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001753
```

e.g.

```
<%= cycle("even", "odd", :name => "row_class") -%>
```

The name is just used to avoid collisions if you've got 2 cycles going on at the same time, it's optional.

Comment: +1: if the OP does not want to use modulo, then using then prescribed method for his platform is the way to go

Comment: thanks! <%= cycle("even", "odd", :name => "row_class") -%>

why the "-" at the end of the -%> though?

Comment: The trailing -%> just tells ERB to remove any whitespace after the closing %> tag. It's generally not necessary if you're just writing out a class name. I just wrote it out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that very easily using jQuery, if that's an option.  Link to the jQuery library in the head, and ideally give the table an id or class so that you can identify it, and create a class that half the rows will get.  Then, put this in your javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#table tr:even').addClass('stripes'); //could also be tr:odd
});
```

That's it, really.  If you don't want to create a separate class, you can always add the style on the fly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#table tr:even').css({'backgroundColor: blue', 'font: red'});
});
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but how would you determine what rows should have the tr:even attribute?

Comment: What the selector is doing is only choosing rows that are even (0, 2, 4 etc.) so that you don't need to.  You can set it to odd, if you prefer.  So every other row will have your 'stripes' class attached/receieve the style declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually built-in to Rails - check the "cycle" method in ActionView Helpers.